# How to troubleshoot metrics-server on kubeadm?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, kubeadm

I have a working 1.15.1 kubenetes cluster using kubeadm on bare-metal and just deployed metrics-server as in the docs:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server.git
kubectl create -f metrics-server/deploy/1.8+/
```

After some time I try `kubectl top node` and I get as response:

> error: metrics not available yet

Also when I try `kubectl top pods` I get:

> W0721 20:01:31.786615 21232 top_pod.go:266] Metrics not available for
>   pod default/pod-deployment-57b99df6b4-khh84, age: 27h31m59.78660593s
>   error: Metrics not available for pod
>   default/pod-deployment-57b99df6b4-khh84, age: 27h31m59.78660593s

I checked the pod and service for metrics-server and all of them are running fine. Where should I try to see a problem?

Comment: Can you add logs of the metric server to question?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Edit the metric-server deployment like Subramanian Manickam's answer said, you can also do it with

```
$ kubectl edit deploy -n kube-system metrics-server
```

That will open a text editor with the deployment yaml-file where you can make the following changes:

Under **spec.template.spec.containers**, on the same level as `name: metrics-server` add

```
args:
- --kubelet-insecure-tls
- --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
- --metric-resolution=30s
```

and then under **spec.template.spec** at the same level as `containers` I **also had to add**:

```
hostNetwork: true
```

to fix the metrics-server working with the CNI (calico in my case).

Afterwards your deployment yaml should look something like this:

```
[...]
spec:
  [...]
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        k8s-app: metrics-server
      name: metrics-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls
        - --metric-resolution=30s
        image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.3
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: metrics-server
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: tmp-dir
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      hostNetwork: true
[...]
```

After that it took about 10-15s for `kubectl top pods` to return some data.

Comment: I am also using calico with hostNetwork.. where do you see the difference if you add hostnetwork?

Comment: When a pod is configured with `hostNetwork: true`, the applications running there can directly see the network interfaces of the host machine where the pod was started. For me that fixed it, because as far as I understood there was an issue reaching the metrics-server for me, even after adding the args.

When running `kubectl get apiservice v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io -o yaml` (without hostNetwork enabled), there was an error reaching the service. Without it, there isn't.

Answer (score 7):

You have to add this command section after line number #33 on [metrics-server-deployment.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/blob/master/deploy/1.8%2B/metrics-server-deployment.yaml) file.

```
  command:
    - /metrics-server
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
    - --kubelet-insecure-tls
```

Once you have updated the file, you have to re-deploy the pod.