# cannot get kubernetes metrics-server apiservice get going (AVAILABLE: False (FalseDiscoveryCheck)

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kube-apiserver, metrics-server, cri-o

I recently gathered a 1 master 3 worker cluster on Naver cloud platform.

However, I am stuck deploying a metrics-server and stuck here for weeks.

In short, my kube-apiserver cannot reach metrics-server apiservice (v1beta1)

error log from: kubectl logs kube-apiserver-master -n kube-system:

> E0229 08:54:20.172156       1 available_controller.go:460] v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io failed with: failing or missing response from https://192.168.182.16:10250/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: Get "https://192.168.182.16:10250/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
>
> E0229 08:08:18.569700       1 controller.go:113] loading OpenAPI spec for "v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io" failed with: Error, could not get list of group versions for APIService)

So I searched the web and tried adding "--kubelet-insecure-tls" flag to metrics-server deployment or adding "hostNetwork: true" config under spec.container under the same manifest that I added the flag above (which ended up in a CrashLoopBackOff state for the metrics-server pod)

I am not sure what is the cause of metrics-server apiservice not working. Maybe I though "v1beta1" api is deprecated or too old for k8s 1.28.x?

Another speculation is metrics-server not deploying when I set "hostNetwork: true" in the deployment manifest of metrics-server.

My master node OS is Ubuntu 20.04, two of the worker nodes the same and one worker node Ubuntu 18.04.

Kubernetes version is 1.28.x across the four nodes and using CRI-O as CRI. Also, using Calico as CNI (reason I added "hostNetwork: true" to metrics-server deployment manifest, which didn't work)

metrics-server version that I am trying to deploy is the latest version 0.7.x.

Here is the components.yaml that I use to deploy metrics-server via "k apply -f components.yaml":

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-admin: "true"
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-edit: "true"
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-view: "true"
  name: system:aggregated-metrics-reader
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - metrics.k8s.io
  resources:
  - pods
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: system:metrics-server
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes/metrics
  verbs:
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server-auth-reader
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: extension-apiserver-authentication-reader
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server:system:auth-delegator
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:auth-delegator
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: system:metrics-server
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:metrics-server
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: metrics-server
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: metrics-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --cert-dir=/tmp
        - --secure-port=10250
        #- --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalDNS,InternalIP,ExternalDNS,ExternalIP,Hostname
        - --kubelet-use-node-status-port
        #- --metric-resolution=15s
        - --metric-resolution=30s
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls
        # command:
        # - /metrics-server
        # - --kubelet-insecure-tls
        # - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
        image: registry.k8s.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.7.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /livez
            port: https
            scheme: HTTPS
          periodSeconds: 10
        name: metrics-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 10250
          name: https
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /readyz
            port: https
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 10
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 1000
          seccompProfile:
            type: RuntimeDefault
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: tmp-dir
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      # below option was added for using Calico CNI
      hostNetwork: true
      priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
      serviceAccountName: metrics-server
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: tmp-dir
---
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
spec:
  group: metrics.k8s.io
  groupPriorityMinimum: 100
  # insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: false
  service:
    name: metrics-server
    namespace: kube-system
  version: v1beta1
  versionPriority: 100
```

By request on the comment, here is /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml args:

```
these are the args in /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml:

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubeadm.kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver.advertise-address.endpoint: 10.0.0.7:6443
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --advertise-address=10.0.0.7
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    #- --requestheader-allowed-names=aggregator
    - --enable-aggregator-routing=true
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --secure-port=6443
    - --service-account-issuer=https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
    - --service-account-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
    - --v=4
```

In addition, I have initialized kubeadm via this command:

$ sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --cri-socket unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock --kubernetes-version v1.28.2

Best,

Comment: Could you please share your kube-apiserver exec args or just confirm if you have configured the flags to enable [aggregation layer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-aggregation-layer/#enable-kubernetes-apiserver-flags)?

Comment: @emdneto I've added content in the body per your request.

Answer (score 0):

Kubelet certificate needs to be signed by cluster Certificate Authority (or disable certificate validation by passing --kubelet-insecure-tls to Metrics Server)

Reference: [kubernetes metrics server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server)

Please see the solution given in [How to troubleshoot metrics-server on kubeadm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137683/how-to-troubleshoot-metrics-server-on-kubeadm) on adding --kubelet-insecure-tls argument

Under spec.template.spec.containers, on the same level as name: metrics-server add

```
args:
- --kubelet-insecure-tls
- --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
- --metric-resolution=30s
```

Comment: As I posted the manifest used for "kubectl apply -f", I have already added those arguments. I don't think your answer works for my case...

Comment: Please check if metric api is responding

#kubectl describe apiservice v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io

Also run 

#curl -k https://192.168.182.16:10250/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1

from both control plane and worker node and see if that's responding

Comment: Thank you for the follow up... kubectl describe apiservice v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io works. curl command does not. any clues from here?